# undefined method `valid?' for "city":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am getting this error when when I try to validate. I am trying to validate whether if the string is not in the DB.

**this is my model**

```
class Location < Locations::Location
  validate do
    #strong URL check for url_prefix
    errors.add(:url_prefix,  "URL already taken") if self.url_prefix.valid?  && is_on_web;
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. `url_prefix` is a string and strings don't have an instance method called `valid?`. You can only call `valid?` on an ActiveRecord object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead use,

```
validates :url_prefix, :uniqueness => { :message => "URL already taken and is online" }
```

update:

conditional validation can be added to solve your second problem like this,

```
validates :url_prefix, :uniqueness => { :message => "URL already taken and is online" }, :if => :is_on_web?
```

Comment: Is there a way i can check :url_prefix for uniqueness and if another thing is true or false ?

Comment: and what is that another thing?